# How to create a new folder in Win10 and why does the old shortcut Alt+F, W, F no longer work?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts

I know in Win10's Explorer the keyboard shortcut for create new folder is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>, but why does <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F</kbd>-<kbd>W</kbd>-<kbd>F</kbd> no longer work?

Comment: ok done........

Answer (score 1):

The existential answer is because in Win10, <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F</kbd>-<kbd>W</kbd> opens a menu that continues to

- -<kbd>F</kbd> for *Open a New Window*
- -<kbd>P</kbd> for *Open a New Window in a New Process*

As for the wisdom why this is so, and why you cannot use the same shortcut you used in XP, Vista, Win7, I cannot answer.

Answer (score 1):

Press <kbd>Menu key</kbd>, <kbd>W</kbd>, <kbd>F</kbd>

If your keyboard doesn't have a [Menu key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menu_key) then use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>

Comment: That's the first time I've ever used the Menu Key. Found it to the right of my right Windows key.

Answer (score 0):

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>, <kbd>W</kbd>, <kbd>F</kbd>.

The <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> brings up the Home tab in Explorer,
and <kbd>W</kbd> is for neW item,
and<kbd>F</kbd> is for Folder.

The statistical answer to why the old shortcut doesn't work, is Windows has historically changed things you'd rather they didn't, such as when the menus in Word 2003 and older changed from a traditional File-View-Tools tree, to the to the now "Contextual Tabs" menus in Word 2007 and later.